# How can i fix the problem using mysql command?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write this type of query for my project , but I can't.
I know there is a problem in the query. 
I want to insert some value in database from another table and and insert new value in same database table

```
INSERT into project_result (project_id, student_id, category, language, project_title) 
SELECT project_id,student_id,category,language,project_title 
FROM participants AND INSERT into project_result(marks) VALUES(90)
```

Comment: erm ... how can this be related to javascript?

Comment: nodejs, reactjs, mongodb seems to be some extra tags too

Comment: actually i am new on stackoverflow ! that's why i put those tag badly...

Answer (score 1):

You can also include constant values directly in an `INSERT ... SELECT` query such as you have written. Try this:

```
INSERT into project_result (project_id, student_id, category, language, project_title, marks) 
SELECT project_id, student_id, category, language, project_title, 90
FROM participants
```

Note that you probably want a `WHERE` condition on your `SELECT` otherwise you will copy *all* data from `participants` to `project_result`.